# Keeping sales and purchase data in the same table?

Tags: database-design

If my `purchase` and `sales` tables retain similar information, is there any problem with moving them to the same table and using an INT column to denote whether a row *represents* a *purchase* or a sale?

If there's additional specific information for either, could I retain it in, say, a `link` table?

Answer (score 4):

Even if you can at this point, it's not clear that you should.

We'll assume most of the potential technical issues don't apply: that `sales` or `purchases` don't connect to some other tables for example.

If you were going to do it, then shifting one or two columns, especially if not heavily used, off to a new linked table could work.

You could update indexes to include the new type column.

**However**, sales and purchases are logically different, and are used in different ways. Even if today they have few differences, that could change dramatically with time. New fields could be required, or new business rules or constraints, that might be difficult to support from the new single table.

Any reports would need to be updated, and would have to reference the new type column, and reference it correctly (which might seem easy, but....).

Various activities performed by your finance people could be complicated by this. If you ever moved to a double-entry accounting system, then the accounts affecting by the purchase of an item vs the sale of an item might be completely different. You would want them to sign off on the change.

Finally, you'd need to make sure that any auditors you may have to deal with would be OK with the change.

Meanwhile, what's the benefit? You might actually take up more database space (you have all the existing data, plus the need for at least one new column in every row). You've added another field to check to most queries involving the two tables now.

Ultimately, the two entities are logically significantly different, and your new structure hides that complexity, rather than emphasizing it.

All that said, I wouldn't say with 100% certainty that this change couldn't work out well for you - I would just want to be sure that it was very well thought out, that all relevant stakeholders were aware, and agreed - and, perhaps most importantly, that it resolved a real problem or concern about the current structure.

Comment: The main purpose I was considering this was because I wanted to make the additional sales/purchase information like client details extension tables for inventory movement instead of having more tables to record the same information. I was just thinking since I've already gone this far with normalization maybe it's not a bad idea to normalize it further. You make valid points and I might rethink even the original intention.

Comment: It's not only the *structure* of data that counts, you have to consider the *semantics*. Later on, you *might* consider the technical implications, if they *hurt* your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do that. Think about how the data is stored on disk. If you store sales and purchase information in the same table, the data might end up getting stored in the same blocks. When you try to retrieve sales data, the database will end up scanning purchase data too to get data pertaining to a list of sales orders. This is assuming that no index is being used. Even if indexes are used, more blocks will need to be scanned to get the same data. So there is likely to be a performance penalty.

Comment: Would you consider this an issue as well if you store other methods of adding to inventory via the same table as purchase differentiated by an indexed integer type column?

Answer (score 0):

A Sale != a Purchase.

They are different entities and tables should represent distinct entities.

There is no problem having many tables in a database - you can however create problems by mixing different entities in the same table - these have been outlined in other answers.

As your system evolves, the differences between a sale and a purchase will become more pronounced. BTW, you should either have singular or plural names for tables, but pick one system and stick to it (I recommend singular).

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated the future possibility of different fields and different uses means you probably don't want them in the same table.

However depending on the use of your database I will mention a way I've seen companies combine Sales and Purchases:

An Inventory Transaction table that stores any activity that impacted inventory. These tables combine Sales and Purchasing but only store basic information like the ID of the transaction, type of transaction, product, qty change, warehouse/store where inventory changed.

So this is an example of a table where it could be useful but that doesn't inherently mean you should do this. For the companies I've seen, I've never seen just an Inventory Transaction table... also had Sales and Purchases tables. This means there was duplicate data but for them it was okay because they were more focused on fast reporting of data.